# How do I cycle through pictures in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My html:

```
<img src="C:\Users\Shady\Downloads\restaurant\food1.jpg" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotator">
```

My Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
            var imageDir = 'C:\\Users\\Shady\\Downloads\\restaurant\\';                          
            var delayInSeconds = 5;                            

            var images = ['food1.jpg', 'food2.jpg', 'food3.jpg', 'food4.jpg', 'food5.jpg', 'food6.jpg', 'food7.jpg', 'food8.jpg'];

            var num = 0;
            var changeImage = function() {
                var len = images.length;
                rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
                if (num == len) {
                    num = 0;
                }
            };
            setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
        })();
        </script>
```

Everything makes sense to me but for some reason it is not working. It is only showing the first picture (doesn't cycle through the pictures). Please let me know if you need anything else. Thank you.

Comment: By rotate do you mean change images from a list (cycle through them) or actually rotate them, like change the orientation by x degrees?

Comment: Cycle.. I changed the title/description.

Comment: looks fine for me, check th `rotator` variable with `console.log`. maybe the JavaScript doesnt finds the div, becuase the DOM isnt ready

Comment: Where is the script placed? before or after the img tag?

Comment: I tried a test function by defining it as `var testf = function() {...` and then I used it in setInterval. It did not work. I changed it to `function testf() {...` and used it in setInterval. It worked.

Comment: It is placed in the head tag.

Comment: @juice then you should use `window.onload = function(){yourfunctioncontenthere};` because otherwise the javascript get's executed before the body of the document is loaded and the element with id `rotator` can't be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are getting element 'rotator' before document is loaded so it doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
function start() {
    var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
    var imageDir = 'C:\\Users\\Shady\\Downloads\\restaurant\\';                          
    var delayInSeconds = 1;                            

    var images = ['food1.jpg', 'food2.jpg', 'food3.jpg', 'food4.jpg', 'food5.jpg', 'food6.jpg', 'food7.jpg', 'food8.jpg'];

    var num = 0;
    var changeImage = function() {
        var len = images.length;
        rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
        if (num == len) {
            num = 0;
        }
    };
    setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
};
window.onload=function(){
start();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Preload the images:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() // create new array to preload images
slideimages[0] = new Image() // create new instance of image object
slideimages[0].src = "firstcar.gif" // set image src property to image path, preloading image in the process
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "secondcar.gif"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "thirdcar.gif"

</script>
```

Display the first image:

```
<img src="firstcar.gif" id="slide" width="100" height="56" />
```

Create the slideshow(cycle):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//variable that will increment through the images
var step=0

function slideit(){
//if browser does not support the image object, exit.
if (!document.images)
return
document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
if (step<2)
step++
else
step=0
//call function "slideit()" every 2.5 seconds
setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

slideit()

</script>
```

Comment: This actually was the one I needed because of the organization of the array items, and it works very simply. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can try...it works fine for me....

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/test1 (2).jpg" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotator"> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
        var imageDir = 'file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/';                         
        var delayInSeconds = 5;                            

        var images = ['test1.jpg', 'test1 (2).jpg', 'test1 (3).jpg', 'test1 (4).jpg', 'test1 (5).jpg', 'test1 (6).jpg', 'test1 (7).jpg', 'test1 (8).jpg'];

        var num = 0;
        var changeImage = function() {
            var len = images.length;
            rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
            if (num == len) {
                num = 0;
            }
        };
        setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 100);
    })();
    </script>   
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: script is out of body

Answer (score 1):

You try to access the DOM element with the id `rotator` before it got loaded.
There are two ways to bypass this problem:

1. You can move your `script` tag below the `img` tag, because then the javascript get's execute after the `img` element has been loaded:

   ```
   <img src="C:\Users\Shady\Downloads\restaurant\food1.jpg" alt="rotating image" width="400" height="300" id="rotator">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       (function() {
           var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
           var imageDir = 'C:\\Users\\Shady\\Downloads\\restaurant\\';                          
           var delayInSeconds = 5;                            

           var images = ['food1.jpg', 'food2.jpg', 'food3.jpg', 'food4.jpg', 'food5.jpg', 'food6.jpg', 'food7.jpg', 'food8.jpg'];

           var num = 0;
           var changeImage = function() {
               var len = images.length;
               rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
               if (num == len) {
                   num = 0;
               }
           };
           setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
       })();
   </script>
   ```
2. You can set the onload event handler for the document to your anonymous function (or give it a name if you like):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
       var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  
       var imageDir = 'C:\\Users\\Shady\\Downloads\\restaurant\\';                          
       var delayInSeconds = 5;                            

       var images = ['food1.jpg', 'food2.jpg', 'food3.jpg', 'food4.jpg', 'food5.jpg', 'food6.jpg', 'food7.jpg', 'food8.jpg'];

       var num = 0;
       var changeImage = function() {
           var len = images.length;
           rotator.src = imageDir + images[num++];
           if (num == len) {
               num = 0;
           }
       };
       setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
   };
   </script>
   ```